# Can I migrate the installed OpenAM to another machine?

Tags: openam

Thank you everyone in advance... ^^;

My manager asked me to migrate the installed OpenAM (already used) to another machine (newly obtained).

I tried to migrate it by file level.
 (.openamcfg folder, openam folder, tomcat whole folder, ...)

But, after file migration... first access to /openam, it showed initial page(wizard) again. (no using installed configurations)

So, I should do first step. (amadmin password setting, and so on...)

Hmm... Is there any solution for pre-installed OpenAm instance migration?

If No, I can tell her there's no migration way.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating the files should be enough, however you must make sure that :

- The `.openamcfg` folder is in Tomcat's home folder
- The file inside the `.openamcfg` folder contains a valid path to the `openam` folder
- The `.openamcfg` and `openam` folders can be read/write by the user who runs the Tomcat service
- The webapp context (the part of the URL after the server's IP address, typically `/openam`) stays the same

Also, when you copy the files, you must first properly stop the Tomcat service, especially if you use OpenAM's embedded datastore.

Comment: Migrating the files is only enough if you keep all FQDNs, otherwise you have to do some work.

If you see the config screen then typically OpenAM can not reach its configuration store.

Comment: The .openamcfg folder is in Tomcat's home folder. can you explain this in more detail?